# How many hosts can one network card handle

Tags: networking, arp, spoofing

When arp spoofing an entire subnet how many hosts can a normal network card handle?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Perhaps try SuperUser?

Comment: How many hosts can *which* network card handle? They're all different. And there are also virtual adapters ... sounds like you need to do more reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is properly implemented, the ip command should allow for as many mac addresses as you want. [see this answer for more details](https://serverfault.com/a/224295)